# Doxygen warnings

Tags: c++, doxygen

My compiler has issued warnings when i try to use doxygen with my cpp file. See below. What must i change to suit the doxygen? Your help is much appreciated.

/home/user/cpplab4/list.cpp:33: warning: documented symbol `CS150::list::list' was not declared or defined.

/home/user/cpplab4/list.cpp:46: warning: documented symbol `node * CS150::list::make_node' was not declared or defined.

```
  /****************************************************************/ 
  /*!
  * \class CS150
  * \brief namespace
  * 
  */
  /****************************************************************/ 

   /**********************************************************************/
   /*!

   * \class CS150::list() 

   * \brief initialise the_list, constructor 

   */
   /**********************************************************************/ 
list::list() 
{  
    the_list = nullptr;
    list_size =0;
}
   /**********************************************************************/
   /*!
   * \class CS150::node *list::make_node(int val)
   * \brief Allocate memory and set members.
   * \param val to be placed in new node    
   * \return return node  
   */
    /*********************************************************************/

node *list::make_node(int val)
{
    node *pnode = new node;
    pnode->value = val;
    pnode->next = nullptr;  
    return pnode;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments say the following:

> `\class CS150`

"There is a class called `CS150`."

> `\class CS150::list()`

"There is a class called `CS150::list()`.".

> `\class CS150::node *list::make_node(int val)`

"There is a class called `CS150::node *list::make_node(int val)`".

None of these statements is true, and it's really confusing Doxygen. It looks like you are trying to document *everything* (including a namespace?) with the command `\class`. But that command is for, well, classes.

I think you probably meant `\class list` in that first block (though this doesn't appear to serve any purpose), and all the others should be removed: Doxygen knows which function you're documenting and what it's called. There's no need and no way to tell it that.

So, for example, just:

```
/*!
 * \brief Allocate memory and set members.
 * \param val to be placed in new node    
 * \return return node  
 */
node *list::make_node(int val)
{
    node *pnode = new node;
    pnode->value = val;
    pnode->next = nullptr;  
    return pnode;
}
```

I recommend you go through the Doxygen documentation again for ideas on how best to use it.

Comment: /home/user/cpplab4/list.cpp:43: warning: documented symbol `node * CS170::list::make_node' was not declared or defined.

Comment: Well, this is the warning i got:

Comment: /home/user/cpplab4/list.cpp:46: warning: documented symbol `node * CS170::list::make_node' was not declared or defined.

Comment: after removing the class thing

Comment: You already pasted that. I'm asking you to _show us_ what you did, when you "removed the class thing". You can use a pastebin website for this for now.

Comment: and now the warning for some reason is in my codes now. /home/user/cpplab4/list.cpp:46 is giving warning on 'node *list::make_node(int val)'

Comment: /******************************************************************************/ 
/*!
* \brief Allocate memory and set members.
* \param val to be placed in new node    
* \return return node  
*/
/******************************************************************************/ 
 node *list::make_node(int val)
 {
  node *pnode = new node;
  pnode->value = val;
  pnode->next = nullptr;  
  return pnode;
 }

Comment: Pastebin is really not difficult to use. You paste in your code, then tell us the URL. Please give that a try.

Comment: I can't explain why you're still getting that warning.

Comment: I'll try and use pastebin hold on

Comment: You still have `\class CS150` in there. What are you trying to achieve with that line?

Comment: Actually i do not have a clue as well lol. Was just doing a test, but i did remove it before and it still gives me errors man. didn't help at all.

Comment: I don't believe that. Without mentioning `CS150` in your Doxygen markup, there's no reason for it to mention "CS150" back to you. Please study the Doxygen documentation carefully to find out what each statement does, rather than just guessing. Good luck!

Comment: Aight, will do that. Thanks for your help nevertheless!